# Algorithm Help Needed with Aggregated Percentages

Tags: php, algorithm, math, percentage

I'm trying to figure out how to build a specific algorithm (ultimately implemented in PHP, but that's less important), but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the best way to do the math.  Instead of defining a complex industry-specific process, I'll use a crazy metaphor here (the math is what's important).  Imagine you're trying to identify the percent chance a specific make of car is parked in a store's parking lot based on the items sold within the store.  To begin you take a physical survey of 100,000 store parking lots, recording each unique car make spotted outside, each unique item sold within the store, and a fixed percent relevance that item has to the store (ex: lumber has an 89% relevance to Home Depot, but pencils only have a 23% relevance to Walmart).

There are two parts to what I’m trying to solve.  First, I’m trying to figure out the best way to roll-up this data to a specific item, while respecting each relevance percent and the number of confirmed observations (so one spotting doesn’t equal 100% chance, similar to http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html ).  In other words, if a brand new, never-before-seen store is  selling Waterford glasses and cashmere sweaters, from those items we can predict there’s an 89% chance a Mercedes is in the parking lot.

So to recap:
Each item has been seen a specific number of times in a store.  For each of those times, there is a different product/store relevance percentage and a list of all car makes in the parking lot.  How do I best mathematically calculate the percent chance a specific make is in the parking lot of a brand new store, only based on the items within?

Now the second part of this is getting a bit more complicated by adding another layer of abstraction.  If a single person visits 50 stores, and we aggregate all the items in all those stores, we can predict what type of car they drive (ex: lots of camping and hiking stores, so they have a 67% chance of driving a Jeep).  Then if they visit a new store and are exposed to a brand new item, for which we have no data, I need to apply that 67% Jeep onto the new item (still respecting the relevance of that item to the store).  Then use that item’s less-than-certain Jeep statistic to influence our predictions of parking lots that contain that new item (which was never directly measured).  Perhaps this requires us to add a confidence interval of some kind?  Or how can we represent that uncertainty, without every one of the millions of items we analyze eventually averaging out to 50%?

I REALLY appreciate your help on this!

Comment: This looks like an exercise in statistics, and the algorithms should be pretty straightforward and/or classical once you get the equations worked out. Likely it will involve inference in mixture models. I think this question is better suited for math.stackexchange, and then once you have the models and abstract inference algorithms from there, you can post here if you're having difficulty implementing.

Comment: Also, it's not very clear what "relevance of an item to a store" means, other than maybe the expected rate at which the item is sold at the store, averaged over the distribution on car types. If you mean something else, you should clarify.

Comment: An item's relevance to a store is a percent identified from elsewhere in the company.  It's just a simple percent - the higher the percent, the more closely related the product is with the store (such as cell phones having a very high relation to AT&T Stores).  Nothing more than a basic percentage in this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to build cross-correlation matrix,
where lines are goods, and columns are car types.
Each cell contains normalized coefficient, how to some
good (i.e. diamond ring) is related to car type (Geo or Mercedes).

Details see here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation

Comment: That seems like it might be a bit heavy handed.  I was thinking something more simple like "add these together and multiple by X" or what-not.  Do you think something like this is really required here?

Comment: Yes, this is "add together and multiply". For each possible combination of pair good/car.